# I got a "Warning: Array subscript have type 'char'" on Code::Block IDE?

Tags: c

When I am running this variadic function I am getting warning `array subscript has type 'char'`, and then it crashes. I suspect the problem occurs somewhere in the `while` loop. I already tried many methods to prevent this function from crashing. For example: I tried changing `(argp, char)` to `(argp, int)` but this will not produce correct output . I also not allowed to change the prototype function. Please help!

```
char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ...) {
    char j;
    int max = 0;
    int fre[255] = { 0 };
    char temp;
    va_list argp;

    if (c == '\0')
        return '\0';
    va_start(argp, c);

    //This for loop will run through the arguments
    //and record their frequencies into fre[] array
    while ((temp = va_arg(argp, char)) != '\0') {
        ++fre[temp];
        if (fre[temp] > max) {
            max = fre[temp];
            j = temp;
        }
    }
    va_end(argp);

    return j;
}
```

Comment: Type `char` can (implementation defined) be signed, so the index can be negative.

Comment: The first element is not processed. In case of only the first element(E.g `'c','\0'`), an uninitialized variable `j` is returned. and `va_arg(argp, char)` --> `va_arg(argp, int)`

Comment: Aside: `int fre[255]` ==> `int fre[256]`

Comment: The warning is almost certainly emitted by your compiler.  It appears right before the crash only because you run the program immediately after compiling it (possibly because your IDE performs a compiler + run combination via a single control).  But that does not mean the warning is unrelated to the crash.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely make `temp` an `unsigned char` or use a cast as you use it to index into the array `fre`. `char` can be, and often is, signed by default so any negative values would access outside the boundaries of the array. By the way, you should make `fre` one item larger to accommodate for all 8-bit values, including `255`.

Note that you do not count the first argument, so `fancyMostFrequentChar('a', 'b', 'a', '\0')` would return `'b'` instead of `'a'`.

Note also (as commented by M.M) that the first argument should be defined as `int` for `va_start` to have defined behavior:

> **7.16.1.4 The `va_start` macro**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdarg.h>
> void va_start(va_list ap, parmN);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `va_start` macro shall be invoked before any access to the unnamed arguments.
>
> The `va_start` macro initializes `ap` for subsequent use by the `va_arg` and `va_end` macros. [...]
>
> The parameter `parmN` is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list in the function definition (the one just before the , ...). If the parameter `parmN` is declared with the `register` storage class, with a function or array type, or with a type that is not compatible with the type that results after application of the default argument promotions, the behavior is undefined.

You mention you are not supposed to change the prototype... Unfortunately the prototype as posted `char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ...)` cannot be used to access the arguments past the first one.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char fancyMostFrequentChar(int c, ...) {
    int fre[256] = { 0 };
    char temp, res = (char)c;

    if (res != '\0') {
        va_list argp;
        va_start(argp, c);

        ++fre[(unsigned char)res];    
        //This for loop will run through the arguments
        //and record their frequencies into fre[] array
        while ((temp = va_arg(argp, char)) != '\0') {
            if (++fre[(unsigned char)temp] > fre[(unsigned char)res]) {
            res = temp;
        }
        va_end(argp);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`va_arg(argp, char)` is undefined behaviour.  The use of `va_arg` macro requires that the type be unchanged under the [default argument promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) -- which means you can't use `float`, nor any integer type narrower than `int`. (Character types are integer types).  Reference: C11 7.16.1.1/2

It is also undefined behaviour to have the second argument to `va_start` be of a type that changes under the default argument promotions. So it is actually impossible to correctly access the variadic arguments for a function declared as `char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ...)`.

To fix this you **must** change the prototype of the function, for example:

```
char fancyMostFrequestChar(int c, ...)
```

and the relevant part of your loop should be:

```
int temp;

while ((temp = va_arg(argp, int)) != '\0')
{
    unsigned char index = (unsigned char)temp;
```

and then use `index` as your array index. It is then guaranteed to be in the range of `1` through to `UCHAR_MAX` (which is usually `255`).  For pedantic correctness you could change your array definition to be `int fre[UCHAR_MAX+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of problems, I hope I will catch all.

```
unsigned char fancyMostFrequentChar(unsigned char c, ...) // resolve ambigity of char
{
    unsigned char j = '\0';   // was not initialized 
    int max = 0;
    int fre[256] = {0};    // max unsigned char is 255 -> array length = 256 (0..255)
    unsigned char temp;
    va_list argp;

    if (c == '\0')
        return '\0';
    va_start(argp, c);

    //This for loop will run through the arguments
    //and record their frequencies into fre[] array
    while ((temp = va_arg(argp, unsigned char)) != '\0')
    {
        ++fre[temp];
        if (fre[temp] > max)
        {
            max = fre[temp];
            j = temp;
        }
    }

    va_end(argp);

    return j;
}
```

Comment: The `memset` is not required, `int fre[256] = {0};` initializes also all values to `0`.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the function i.e from char to unsigned char because that is how the program will be graded.

Comment: @Lucas Jack: The day will come ;-)